# Why I can't insert a range column parition

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table with a large amount of data and this data is already splitted into paritions. Now I want to add a new partition for a new type of dataset.

The current table looks like this:

```sql
create table audit_log
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment,
    inserted_at datetime default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' not null,
    eventType varchar(50) not null,
    eventTableName varchar(255) default '' not null,
    entityId int unsigned null,
    matchId int unsigned null,
    userId int unsigned null,
    route varchar(255) null,
    changes longtext null,
    primary key (id, eventTableName, inserted_at)
)
collate=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

There are several partitions based on the `eventTableName` and the `inserted_at` column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE audit_log PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (eventTableName, inserted_at)  (
    PARITION day_referee_statistics_20190902 VALUES LESS THAN ('referee_statistics','2019-09-03'),
    PARITION day_referee_statistics_20190903 VALUES LESS THAN ('referee_statistics','2019-09-04'),
    PARITION referee_future VALUES LESS THAN ('referee_statistics',MAXVALUE),
    PARITION day_team_statistics_20190902 VALUES LESS THAN ('team_statistics','2019-09-03'),
    PARITION day_team_statistics_20190903 VALUES LESS THAN ('team_statistics','2019-09-04'),
    PARITION team_statistics_future VALUES LESS THAN ('team_statistics',MAXVALUE),
    PARITION future VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE, MAXVALUE);
```

And a lot of other partitions...

Now I want to add a new partition for a new table that I want to audit: the `results_future` partition. First I tried to replace the future partition but that failed because there are others with a higher value between. Then I sorted them but still get the same error:

```sql
ALTER TABLE audit_log REORGANIZE PARTITION future_team_statistics INTO (
    PARTITION future_results VALUES LESS THAN ('results',MAXVALUE),
    PARTITION future_team_statistics VALUES LESS THAN ('team_statistics',MAXVALUE)
)
```

Fails with:

> General error: 1493 VALUES LESS THAN value must be strictly increasing for each partition

Comment: maybe I found the error.. let me try one thing :)

Comment: seems I just needed a duck to tell my problems...

Comment: Show us a query for which this partitioning helps.  I suspect that the partitioning is a waste of time.

Comment: The problem is not querying the data. The problem is inserting and removing the data. Partitions split the indexes and therefore an insert updates only a small Index. And removing data is just removing a complete Partition. Anyway: it's not the question.

Comment: Yes, using `DROP PARTITION` is _much_ faster than doing the equivalent `DELETE`.  However, the speed of updating an index is about the same regardless of the size of the index.

Comment: @RickJames good to know, thanks. we never delete on this table we always drop partitions: every partition that is older than x days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest partition between my new partition and the MAXVALUE parition is not the `team_statistics_future` - it is the `day_team_statistics_20190902` parition in this case. So the query would be:

```sql
ALTER TABLE audit_log REORGANIZE PARTITION day_team_statistics_20190902 INTO (
    PARTITION future_results VALUES LESS THAN ('results',MAXVALUE),
    PARTITION day_team_statistics_20190902 VALUES LESS THAN ('team_statistics','2019-09-03')
);
```